# Robots Noindex,Nofollow in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, meta-tags, cakephp-2.2

How do I put this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'noindex'));?>
```

in the head section of my layout from my view?

I've tried the same technique that I use for scripts and css, by adding a second parameter to specify my block, but its not working.

Comment: Which second parameter? `array('inline' => false)`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried :
<?php echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'ROBOTS', 'content' => 'ALL'), array('inline'=> false)) ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'ROBOTS', 'content' => 'ALL'), false) ?>

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'noindex,nofollow'), null, array('inline' => false)) ?>
```

I was missing the second parameter: null

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the test cases, it should work!
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3/lib/Cake/Test/Case/View/Helper/HtmlHelperTest.php#L1520

e.g.

```
echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'ROBOTS', 'content' => 'ALL'));
```

did you try the latest 2.2 head?
just in case there has been some fix in the past correcting the issue.

PS: view blocks havent been introduced until 2.1. you seem to have 2.0 from looking at your tags.

Comment: I've changed my tag, its actually version 2.2.1. The example you show works, but isn't placed in the layout.